# Who can tell if there is a particular difference between using 'PHPSESSID' and 'CAKEPHP'?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Who can tell if there is a specific difference between using 'PHPSESSID' and 'CAKEPHP' in sessions? And if there is, then what?

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html - the documentation does not say anything about it

For the first example, in config/app.php:

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'php'
],

// Output: session cookie - 'CAKEPHP'
```

For the second example, in config/app.php:

```
    'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'PHPSESSID' // for KCFINDER
],

// Output: session cookie - 'PHPSESSID'
```

Does anyone know a particular difference? Maybe something related to security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a technical point of view there is absolutely no difference, it's just the name of the session cookie.

The decision to use `CAKEPHP` as the default was made for whatever reason, a long, long time ago, and [**it might get dropped in 4.x.**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/11584), specifically because there is no point in changing the default. Also using `CAKEPHP` as a name could be used by an attacker to identify the code running the system, so that it could be targeted accordingly, ie it would actually be "safer" to use the PHP defaults.